# Macro enabled template doesn't open Word in SharePoint Online 'New Experience'

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, document-template, new-experience

I have created a new document content type and associated a dotm template to it to be used on a document list.

When I'm in the classic experience of the list and select the template from the 'New' drop down, Word opens and a new document opens based on the template.

If I switch to the 'New Experience' and try the same process, it just creates a new copy of the template as an item in the list.

[image: Test Macro]

[image: Macro in List]

Comment: A long time since your post, but...
This appears to still be an issue in SharePoint Online with the Modern UI.
Did you ever find a way around it??
Your in hope
Ruth

Answer (score 0):

Word Macro-Enabled Document (.docm) or Word Macro-Enabled Template (.dotm) can be opened in word online, but macros do not run and we cannot edit the file in word online.

More information please check the [File formats supported in Word Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-document-in-the-browser-and-in-Word-3e863ce3-e82c-4211-8f97-5b33c36c55f8).

Comment: Thank you for the response, however that is not quite the issue. In the modern view it is creating new .dotm files in the list (shown in the screenshot) but in the classic view it will create a new .docx file based on the template.