# SharePoint Online - using Macro templates on the New button in a Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, word

I am trying to get the following to work in SharePoint online.

1. Adding a dotm Word macro template to the New button
2. Ensure that it opens a document based on that template in Microsoft Word, not Word Online (so the macros work!) **PROBLEM HERE**
3. Give people the chance to move it / work on in in their OneDrive once the document is created

Should be easy! Lots of this I can get half way there, but strange glitches happen.
What happens:

1. Yes I can add a docm file to the library as a template
2. When you select the template it opens a new tab in the browser and just hangs

- a COPY of the dotm file is created in the library - not a docm, but a template file!
- you have to close the blank browser tab, and return to the library and click on the file to open it

3. The user could save as or use the copy button to save to OneDrive, but cannot move the file from within Word?

Is there a way to fix the problem at point 2??? this seems to have been a problem for a while as someone else reported it as an issue in 2018 in this post, but no answers ( [Macro enabled template doesn't open Word in SharePoint Online 'New Experience'](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/229668/macro-enabled-template-doesnt-open-word-in-sharepoint-online-new-experience)).